# MariaDB : convert string to int when importing from CSV, while removing spaces in number

Tags: mysql, csv, replace, import, mariadb

I have a "big" csv file (around 1GB of data, 3M lines) to import into a MariaDB table.

The thing is, almost every field of every line is considered as a string.
So, I have to convert "1 337" (string) into 1337 (integer).

Here is the script used to import into the table :

```
LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL
    INFILE 'data.txt'
    INTO TABLE `test`.`test_import`
    CHARACTER SET utf8
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    ESCAPED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    (`id`,
        `data`,
        @NumberOne,
        @NumberTwo,
        @NumberThree,
        @NumberFour)
        SET `Number One` = REPLACE(@NumberOne, ' ', ''),
            `Number Two` = REPLACE(@NumberOne, ' ', ''),
            `Number Three` = REPLACE(@NumberOne, ' ', ''),
            `Number Four` = REPLACE(@NumberOne, ' ', '');
```

Using this script, there is no problem importing numbers below 999. But beginning with 1000 (written `"1 000"` in my csv), all I have is a warning (`Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '1 000'`) and the value 1 in my database.

The "funny" thing is, when I try with this :

```
SET `Number One` = REPLACE(@NumberOne, '1', 'k'),
                `Number Two` = REPLACE(@NumberOne, '1', 'k'),
                `Number Three` = REPLACE(@NumberOne, '1', 'k'),
                `Number Four` = REPLACE(@NumberOne, '1', 'k')
```

-> REPLACE() *works*, "1 000" become "k 000".

So, how can I use REPLACE() to remove spaces in numbers ? Or, how to make CAST()/CONVERT() working correctly on strings like "1 337" ?

---

Some more informations.

Here is a *fresh* test table :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test_spaces_extr (
    `Identifier`   tinytext,
    `First name`   tinytext,
    `Last name`    tinytext,
    `Number One`   int unsigned,
    `Number Two`   int unsigned,
    `Number Three` int unsigned,
    `Number Four`  int unsigned,
    `Number Five`  int unsigned,
    `Number Six`   int unsigned,
    `Number Seven` int unsigned
);
```

Here is the script to import CSV :

```
LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL
    INFILE 'some_data.txt'
    INTO TABLE `test`.`test_spaces_extr`
    CHARACTER SET utf8
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    ESCAPED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    (`Identifier`,
        `First name`,
        `Last name`,
        @NumberOne,
        @NumberTwo,
        @NumberThree,
        @NumberFour,
        @NumberFive,
        @NumberSix,
        @NumberSeven)
        SET `Number One` = REPLACE(@NumberOne, ' ', ''),
            `Number Two` = REPLACE(@NumberTwo, ' ', ''),
            `Number Three` = REPLACE(@NumberThree, ' ', ''),
            `Number Four` = REPLACE(@NumberFour, ' ', ''),
            `Number Five` = REPLACE(@NumberFive, ' ', ''),
            `Number Six` = REPLACE(@NumberSix, ' ', ''),
            `Number Seven` = REPLACE(@NumberSeven, ' ', '');
```

Here is the full content of `some_data.txt` :

`"3efa639b3a";"Censored";"Censored";"7 896";"3 468";"3 854";"5 000";"1 234";"9 654";"1 337"`

(One line, yes.)

Here is the result :

```
"Identifier"    "First name"    "Last name" "Number One"    "Number Two"    "Number Three"  "Number Four"   "Number Five"   "Number Six"    "Number Seven"
"3efa639b3a"    "Censored"  "Censored"  "7896"  "3468"  "3854"  "5000"  "1234"  "9654"  "0"
```

In fact, the "Number" fields became integers here. All of them, but not the last one ("Number Seven" -> "0").

It's becoming weirder ...

Comment: did you try to set data type as `unsigned int` ?

Comment: @PrabhatG Not really. At the moment, these fields are "integer". But even using `CAST(REPLACE(@var, ' ', '') as unsigned)`, it won't work.It's like if REPLACE() doesn't want to remove spaces.

Comment: @lksen : Just a thought...can you open it in excel and use `=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")` to remove spaces from numeric and then load in MySQL ?

Comment: @PrabhatG Unfortunately, that's not possible, the file is just too big for that

Comment: Let me get this straight, do you see `1 000` or `1`  in your database?

Comment: `1` (integer). If I ALTER `Number One` (or an other "Number" field) to be a tinytext, the value is `1 000` (string).

Comment: Just for a trial, set the data type to unsigned int. `ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name int unsigned;`

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problem:

```bsh
$ mysql -u user -p --column-type-info
```

```sql
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT VERSION();
Field   1:  `VERSION()`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      ``
Org_table:  ``
Type:       VAR_STRING
Collation:  utf8_general_ci (33)
Length:     72
Max_length: 24
Decimals:   31
Flags:      NOT_NULL 


+-----------------+
| VERSION()       |
+-----------------+
| 10.0.31-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT CAST(REPLACE('1 337', ' ', '') AS UNSIGNED);
Field   1:  `CAST(REPLACE('1 337', ' ', '') AS UNSIGNED)`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      ``
Org_table:  ``
Type:       LONGLONG
Collation:  binary (63)
Length:     5
Max_length: 4
Decimals:   0
Flags:      NOT_NULL UNSIGNED BINARY NUM 


+---------------------------------------------+
| CAST(REPLACE('1 337', ' ', '') AS UNSIGNED) |
+---------------------------------------------+
|                                        1337 |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE**

File: `/path/to/data.csv`

```bsh
"3efa639b3a";"Censored";"Censored";"7 896";"3 468";"3 854";"5 000";"1 234";"9 654";"1 337"
```

```sql
MariaDB [_]> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------------+
| VERSION()       |
+-----------------+
| 10.0.31-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_spaces_extr`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

MariaDB [_]> CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `test_spaces_extr` (
    ->     `Identifier`   tinytext,
    ->     `First name`   tinytext,
    ->     `Last name`    tinytext,
    ->     `Number One`   int unsigned,
    ->     `Number Two`   int unsigned,
    ->     `Number Three` int unsigned,
    ->     `Number Four`  int unsigned,
    ->     `Number Five`  int unsigned,
    ->     `Number Six`   int unsigned,
    ->     `Number Seven` int unsigned
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/data.csv'
    ->   INTO TABLE `test_spaces_extr`
    ->   CHARACTER SET utf8
    ->   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
    ->   OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    ->   ESCAPED BY '"'
    ->   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    ->   (
    ->     `Identifier`,
    ->     `First name`,
    ->     `Last name`,
    ->     @`NumberOne`,
    ->     @`NumberTwo`,
    ->     @`NumberThree`,
    ->     @`NumberFour`,
    ->     @`NumberFive`,
    ->     @`NumberSix`,
    ->     @`NumberSeven`
    ->   )
    ->   SET
    ->   `Number One` = REPLACE(@`NumberOne`, ' ', ''),
    ->   `Number Two` = REPLACE(@`NumberTwo`, ' ', ''),
    ->   `Number Three` = REPLACE(@`NumberThree`, ' ', ''),
    ->   `Number Four` = REPLACE(@`NumberFour`, ' ', ''),
    ->   `Number Five` = REPLACE(@`NumberFive`, ' ', ''),
    ->   `Number Six` = REPLACE(@`NumberSix`, ' ', ''),
    ->   `Number Seven` = REPLACE(@`NumberSeven`, ' ', '');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)                  
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [_]> SELECT
    ->   `Identifier`,
    ->   `First name`,
    ->   `Last name`,
    ->   `Number One`,
    ->   `Number Two`,
    ->   `Number Three`,
    ->   `Number Four`,
    ->   `Number Five`,
    ->   `Number Six`,
    ->   `Number Seven`
    -> FROM
    ->   `test_spaces_extr`;
+------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+------------+--------------+
| Identifier | First name | Last name | Number One | Number Two | Number Three | Number Four | Number Five | Number Six | Number Seven |
+------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+------------+--------------+
| 3efa639b3a | Censored   | Censored  |       7896 |       3468 |         3854 |        5000 |        1234 |       9654 |         1337 |
+------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Yup. `REPLACE(str, ' ', '')` (to remove spaces) works in this context, I tested it too. But not when used in the context of importing a CSV.